# What is the $scope – template designpattern called?

Tags: angularjs, design-patterns, handlebars.js

Is there a name for the front-end designpattern that is adopted by for example angular.js and to some degree Mustache/handlbars etc.

that is: you have a (javascript) data-model that is the truth and then create the DOM with some templateing. I have heard MVC(though where is the controller) M-V-VM and mv*. Though I can't really find any definitions for what is what.

Comment: From the Angular folks: https://plus.google.com/+AngularJS/posts/aZNVhj355G2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Wikipedia it's the **[UI data binding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UI_data_binding)** design pattern.

See also: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/databinding